# determine over looping activity in a dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would greatly appreciate  if someone help me out! I am not sure if we can do it in R!

I have 4 columns in my data set. first number of family, second number of persons in that family,  col3 is the number of trips that a person make, col4 the place of the activity of that person and col5 start time of activity , col6 end of activity

```
family    persons    trip      place   mode     loop   start time   end time
   1      1        1         home         -    1         3         8:45
   1      1        2          work       car     1       8:45        13:30
   1      1        3         shopping    walk    1       13:30       15
   1      1        4         home         car    1      15:00        15:30
   1      1        5         friends     walk    2      20:00        22:00
   1      1        6          home        walk   2      22:00       8:30
   1      2        1          home        -      1       3:00        8:00
   1      2        2           work        bus   1      8:00        17:00
   1      2        3           home        bus   1      17:00       3:00
   1      3        1          home       -       1       3:00       23:00
   1      3        2         friend       walk   1        23:00      24:00
```

each loop is a set of activities that start at home and finish at home. for the first person we have 2 loops :

```
  first loop: home-> work -> shoping -> home
  second loop: home -> friends -> home
```

for second person we have 1 loop

```
   loop: home -> work -> home
```

I want to define an indicator to check that if car is available when a person wants to do an activity. the indicator is 1 if loops don't have intersection. So i want to check that if loops have intersection or not for a person who has car and other persons. for example in the above example the first person has a car in his first loop. So car is not available for others in the household from 8:45 to 15:30.
this loop has intersection with the loop of second person since he is working from 8 to 17.(so indicator is 1) but it does not have intersection with the third person since he goes from (23:00 to 24:00). you can ignore rows whose have - in their mode. I just put them to make it clear what is loop.

for second loop of the first person car is available because nobody else drive the car so indicator is 0.

So out put is some thing like this

```
family persons  trip    place     mode  loop   start time     endtime    i
   1      1        1    home         -     1         3           8:45    -
   1      1        2    work       car     1       8:45        13:30     0
   1      1        3    shopping    walk    1       13:30       15       0
   1      1        4    home         bus    1      15:00        15:30    0
   1      1        5    friends     walk    2      20:00        22:00    0
   1      1        6    home        walk   2      22:00       22:30       0
   1      2        1    home        -      1       3:00        8:00      -
   1      2        2    work        bus   1      8:00        17:00       1
   1      2        3    home        bus   1      17:00       3:00        1
   1      3        1    home       -       1       3:00       23:00      -
   1      3        2    friend       walk   1        23:00      24:00    0
```

in other words indicator is 1 if car is not available for a loop, and 0 if it is available.

one of the possibility is that we make a new dataframe with following steps:

1-remove all rows whose place is home.

2-for each loop we have one row with start time is the first trip's start time and end time is the last trip's end time in the loop for each person.

3- mood==car if one of trips has mode car and non-car otherwise

```
family persons  trip    place     mode  loop   start time     endtime    
   1      1        2    work       car     1       8:45        15:30     
   1      1        5    friends   non-car   2      20:00        22:30    
   1      2        2    work      non-car  1      8:00        17:00      
   1      3        2    friend    non-car   1      23:00        24:00
```

Now indicator is 1 if a the person with non-car mode interval time has intersection with the person whose drive car. (mood=car)

```
family persons  trip    place     mode  loop   start time     endtime    i
   1      1        2    work       car     1       8:45        15:30     0
   1      1        5    friends   non-car   2      20:00        22:30    0
   1      2        2    work      non-car  1      8:00        17:00      1
   1      3        2    friend    non-car   1      23:00        24:00    0
```

I know how to do step 1, please help with step 2,3 and indicator

Comment: So basically, if `mode == car` for any two users and if their start and end times overlap, the indicator should be set to `1` for the user with the later start time for the duration of the overlap?

Comment: if mood== car in a loop. it is enough just one of the trip in the loop to have mood==car. then indicator is 1 if another person's activities is taking place when car is not at home.

Comment: one posibility is that start time to be the first and end time the last trip in the loop and mood==car if one of the trips has mood car in the loop. then finding indicator must be easy

Comment: @Dunois please see edit

Comment: Hmm so we don't actually care what the actual `mode` for that person is? If person 2's activity loop overlaps with person 1's activity loop and person 1's loop includes using the car, then we set person 2's indicator (for the duration of the overlap) to 0?

Comment: I think you need an additional column that defines whether or not a particular row needs the car. I don't think it'll be possible to set the indicator meaningfully without this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196948/discussion-between-dunois-and-sherek-66).